# how to run multiple LINQ queries on the same datafile

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to `LINQ` and I am currently using it to process big datasets in csv format (half a million records). I am using a `StreamReader` to open the files and implement the `IEnumerable<>` interface in order to populate the results. Below you can see the main part of the reading code:

```
IEnumerator<Person> IEnumerable<Person>.GetEnumerator()
{
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filename)){
        streamReader.ReadLine();
        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream){
            string[] values = streamReader.ReadLine().Split(new char[] { ',' });
            Person p = new Person();
            p.Name = values[0];
            p.Age = Convert.ToInt16(values[1]);
            p.Score = Convert.ToDouble(values[2]);
            p.PlotArea = Convert.ToInt16(values[3]);
            p.ForecastConsumption = Convert.ToDouble(values[4]);
            p.Postcode = values[5];
            p.PropertyType = values[6];
            p.Bedrooms = Convert.ToInt16(values[7]);
            p.Occupancy = Convert.ToInt16(values[8]);

            yield return p;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is a typical query:

```
var query = from person in reader
            where person.Score > 36.55 && person.Bedrooms < 3
            select person;
```

My question is this, every time I want to run a query the `StreamReader` has to open the file. Is there any way that I can open the file once and run multiple queries?

FYI I am very impressed with LINQ, it takes 1.2 seconds to run the query above. It's just that I will run a lot of rules for the datasets.

Comment: If you're .net4+ you can dispense with the StreamReader altogether and use File.ReadLines instead. It does the same thing (i.e. allows you to enumerate a file without loading it all into memory).

Comment: `reader` is what type? If you want to do all in memory you can also use `File.ReadAllLines`

Comment: Take a look to this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2005/08/06/readlinetextreader.aspx, if files are big you can start with it to build a shared (multithreaded) cache (just remember the current line/position in a per-thread base)

Comment: I love LINQ too but rewrite that query without LINQ and it'll take less than one second (I would say half second if you sacrifice a little your code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is this, every time I want to run a query the StreamReader has to open the file. Is there any way that I can open the file once and run multiple queries?

Well the simplest way would be to load the whole file into a list, e.g.

```
var list = reader.ToList();

// Now run multiple queries over list
```

Obviously that will take quite a lot of memory, but it's going to be the *simplest* way to go. If you want to join multiple queries together, you'll have to work out *exactly* what you want to do - the composition model in LINQ is mostly in terms of *chaining* query operations together rather than building multiple queries from the same source.

Failing that, if neither the complexity of the "multiple queries in one pass" nor the "load the whole file into memory" works for you, you're likely to be stuck with loading it multiple times.

One in-between option which *may* be more memory efficient would be to read all the *lines* into memory (so you only perform the disk activity once) but then *parse* those lines multiple times. That will be much more efficient in terms of IO, but worse in terms of CPU.

Comment: Just keep in mind that doing this involves the entire contents of the file being in memory.  For a large file that may either be a bad idea, or simply not possible.  If the file is very large you may *want* to open the reader and read over the file multiple times.

Comment: Actually it's not an easy task (if the file is big enough). You should abstract your reader using an access object but it may be tricky to move back and forward in the file.

Comment: Hmmmm there is an issue with memory actually as some of the other files are getting to the million+ records. I like the idea of reading all the string lines and doing the parsing multiple times.

Comment: @Dimitris: That still means holding the whole file in memory though. How large is the file? Bear in mind that strings in .NET are UTF-16... so you may even need to hold the *raw binary data* in memory, and convert it into text each time (which is pretty similar to using a memory mapped file).

Comment: @JonSkeet: The file I am using is only for some initial tests. The end simulator will probably use files with 20-50 columns and 500K to 2000K records.

Comment: @Dimitris: Okay. At that point, you really should be thinking about whether a database would be more appropriate...

Comment: @JonSkeet: I wish :). The client wants to be able to use a standalone, lightweight system without any dependencies. In fact I am developing this in Excel using VSTO because they want Excel as the front end.

Comment: @Dimitris: Do you know in advance which columns you'll need across all the queries? You could pare it down to *just* those columns, which could make a big difference in memory usage.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes at some point I will know exactly the number of columns for each datafile so potentially this could help. I think in general that we need to push the boundaries otherwise clients will be restricted forever.

Answer (score 1):

Your situation will be a performance trade-off between:

1. reading the entire file into memory, and running whichever queries you need
2. simply iterating over the file multiple times.

If the latter, try using `File.ReadLines` which provides a nice IEnumerable interface over file IO:

```
public Person ReadPerson(string[] personLine)
{
    Person p = new Person();
    p.Name = personLine[0];
    p.Age = Convert.ToInt16(personLine[1]);
    p.Score = Convert.ToDouble(personLine[2]);
    p.PlotArea = Convert.ToInt16(personLine[3]);
    p.ForecastConsumption = Convert.ToDouble(personLine[4]);
    p.Postcode = personLine[5];
    p.PropertyType = personLine[6];
    p.Bedrooms = Convert.ToInt16(personLine[7]);
    p.Occupancy = Convert.ToInt16(personLine[8]);
}
```

And usage:

```
var file = File.ReadLines("/filepath/")
    .Select(line => ReadPerson(line.Split(',')));

var query = from person in file
    where person.Score > 36.55 && person.Bedrooms < 3
    select person;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
  return from line in File.ReadAllLines(filename)
                     let values = line.Split(new char[] { ',' })
                     select new Person{
                Name = values[0];
                Age = Convert.ToInt16(values[1]);
                Score = Convert.ToDouble(values[2]);
                PlotArea = Convert.ToInt16(values[3]);
                ForecastConsumption = Convert.ToDouble(values[4]);
                Postcode = values[5];
                PropertyType = values[6];
                Bedrooms = Convert.ToInt16(values[7]);
                Occupancy = Convert.ToInt16(values[8]);
            };
```